# terra::union returns a multidimensional SpatVector when an zero-extent object is involved

Tags: r, terra

When two identical SpatVector objects are combined unsing `union`, a new SpatVector object is created that is the same as the original. This is the expected behaviour.

```
a = terra::vect(cbind(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0), c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0)), type = "polygons", crs = "local")
terra::union(a, a)
all.equal(a, terra::union(a, a)) # TRUE
```

However, when SpatVector objects of zero extent are merged, additional dimensions are added.

```
b = terra::vect(cbind(rep(0, 5), rep(0, 5)), type = "polygons", crs = "local")
terra::union(b, b)
all.equal(b, terra::union(b, b)) # Not true (lengths differ).
```

Why are SpatVectors of zero extent handled differently? And is it possible to merge these elegantly? My use case involves adding a series of SpatVectors to create a composite object with the maximum extent of any/all of the components. A zero-extent object should not add anything, so that `terra::union(a, b)` should be the same as `a`. Can anyone help me get there?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is because you are combining two invalid polygons.

```
is.valid(b)
#[1] FALSE
```

Since they are invalid you cannot do a union, and you get them both back? This is an odd corner-case bug that you could [report](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues).

Here is a workaround:

```
b <- unique(b)
```